# Regex match strings with or with a word being present

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, fluentd

am attempting to parse the modsecurity audit log which reports in two different formats ... one being as follows

```
[modsecurity] [client 111.222.333.444 [domain somedomain.com] [403] [/apache/20150718/20150718-1412/20150718-141258-VapQ2kDQOQ1qTs5mQAsHDQAAAIs]  [file \"/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/10_asl_rules.conf\"] [line \"93\"] [id \"392301\"] [rev \"7\"] [msg \"Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: Request Containing Content, but Missing Content-Type header\"] [severity \"NOTICE\"] [tag \"no_ar\"] Access denied with connection close (phase 1). Match of \"rx ^0$\" against \"REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Length\" required.
```

and the second like

```
[modsecurity] [client 111.222.333.444] [domain somedomain.com] [200] [/apache/20150718/20150718-1429/20150718-142952-VapUz0DQOQ1qTs5mQAsHfAAAAIg]  [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/localrules.conf"] [line "3"] [id "999999"] [msg "My WAF Rules - Blocking Wordpress Login Attempt by Country Code"] Warning. Matched phrase "CN" at GEO:COUNTRY_CODE.
```

I have matched the second rule using the regex:

```
 /^\[(?<app>\w+)\](\s+)\[client (?<src_ip>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\](\s+)\[domain (?<domain>.*)\](\s+)\[(?<rcode>\d+)\](\s+)\[(?<audit_data>.*)\](\s+)\[(?<modsec_file>.*)\](\s+)\[line "(?<modsec_line>\d+)"\](\s+)\[id "(?<modsec_ruleid>\d+)"\](\s+)\[msg "(?<modsec_msg>.*)"\].*$/
```

but what I would is to be able to match both formats so basically if the value

```
[rev "\d+"]
```

does not exist then it doesn't matter as long as everything else matches.  Is this possible please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
/^\[(?<app>\w+)\]\s+\[client (?<src_ip>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\]\s+\[domain (?<domain>.*?)\]\s+\[(?<rcode>\d+)\]\s+\[(?<audit_data>.*?)\]\s+\[(?<modsec_file>.*?)\]\s+\[line "(?<modsec_line>\d+)"\]\s+\[id "(?<modsec_ruleid>\d+)"\]\s+(?:\[rev "\d+"\]\s+)?\[msg "(?<modsec_msg>.*)"\].*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW6yS2/1)